# How to trigger other events in MVC, once the desired event completes?

Tags: object-oriented, php, mvc, event-programming

What is a technique in MVC that can be used to trigger updates?

Namely,

When user clicks a button save a product I have this:

```
function saveProduct($product)
{
    $this->repository->saveProduct($product);
}
```

But addition of (any) product must trigger a global state update.  I did it like so:

```
function saveProduct($product)
{
    $this->repository->saveProduct($product);
    $this->repository->updateGlobalState();
}
```

But then I end up with `updateGlobalState` code in every method.. i.e:

```
function saveMotor($motor)
{
    $this->repository->saveMotor($motor);
    $this->repository->updateGlobalState();
}
```

Is there a way to not clutter specific methods but to somehow trigger global state update in a different way so that methods are clutter-free?

Comment: `But then I end up with updateGlobalState code in every method` -- By design.  It's a method call, not a method body; DRY doesn't apply.

Comment: What's inside the `saveProduct` and `saveMotor` methods?

Comment: You could create functions like `Controller::afterSave();` and `Controller::beforeSave();`. In your case you need former only. I provided latter for the sake of a full sample.

Answer (score 3):

The design pattern "**observer**" is exactly what you are looking for.

[Here is a very good documented way of implementing this pattern](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Behavioral/Observer/README.html). And there is code as well.

So your Prodoct would be the observed object (called Subject) and the counterpart is the Observer which gets notified by every update on the product and can react accordingly.

But you still need this notify method in any state changing method of Product.